# Does the compiler use the implicit ‘this’ pointer to figure out if a function belongs to a class?

Tags: c++, class

I’ve heard that with classes, the functions of each class are stored basically exactly like other functions except they have an extra implicit ‘this’ parameter added. The ‘this’ parameter is just a pointer to the class that function belongs to. Is that parameter how the compiler knows a function belongs to a class? If so, couldn’t we easily fool the compiler by just defining a function, giving it a pointer to a particular class, and then call the function from that class with the dot operator?

Some sample code of what I meant:

```
class my_Class {int m_number = 3;};
int my_Function(my_Class* fake_This)
{
  return fake_This->m_number;
}

my_Class sampleClass;
sampleClass.my_Function();
```

Comment: The compiler cannot use pointers to objects, because those only exist at runtime. The compiler doesn't have to "figure anything out". It works the other way around: *because* the compiler knows that the function belongs to a class (it can see *that it was declared* in a way that makes it part of a class: because of the `::` operator or because it is inside a `class {}` block), and *because* it sees method-call syntax, it generates the necessary code such that `this` will have the right value at runtime.

Comment: It's hard to make sense of the question without seeing any code. Could you give an example of something that might be done by "fooling" the compiler? For example, are you trying to make an instance of one class behave as if it had member functions that are defined in an unrelated class? Or are you trying to call a member function as if it were an ordinary function? Or just what?

Comment: The explanation of how `this` is just an extra function argument is simply a way to illustrate how it works. A member function doesn't actually have a hidden `this` argument. The language provides the `this` keyword to access the object the member function was called for. Implementations might implement this using the same mechanism as function arguments but as far as the language is concerned it is not part of its arguments. It will never participate in overload resolution so you can't fool the compiler the way you describe.

Comment: Except with operator overloading where it first looks for `this->operator` and then `operator` taking the object as first argument.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to fool a compiler. Your job as a programmer is to make the compiler's job easy, not hard. Worse, if you write bizzarro compiler-busting code that still produces the required results, your coworkers in maintenance are going to <expletive deleted>ing hate you. Describe the program behaviour clearly and everyone from the computer to the co-op who has to add on new features in a few years down the road will love you. The measure of a programmer is often in how light a curse word their name becomes after they leave the company

Comment: Now that you've added code, the compiler will see this and reject it. It knows `my_class` contains no `my_Function` because it just parsed the class definition and will tell you in no uncertain, but possibly arcane, terms by refusing to compile. You will have to get sneakier than that.

Comment: If you want to poke at this more closely, look into function pointers. [Some groovy reading](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members) on the stuff you can do legally that you can use as a branching off point into the world of the Undefined

Comment: It seems that "fooling the compiler" and "entering the realm of **undefined behavior**" may be the same thing.